# Incorrect data returned from Zend\Form\Form with nested Collections

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-inputfilter

I've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/5046) with Zend about this issue, but I was hoping to get some help sooner.

I have a form with nested Collections. Lets say the data I submit to the form has 2 items in a collection with an additional nested collection, like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'foo' => 'bazbat',
        'bar' => '12345',
        'baz' => '',
        'nest' => array(
            'foo' => 'foobar',
            'bar' => '111111',
            'baz' => '',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'foo' => 'batbaz',
        'bar' => '54321',
        'baz' => '',
        'nest' => array(
            'foo' => 'foobat',
            'bar' => '222222',
            'baz' => '',
        ),
    )
);
```

The above example work fine. However, if the second collection does not have a "nest" input (empty Collection) the "nest" collection from the first collection is added to the second.

Example:

```
$form = new \Zend\Form\Form();
$form->setData(array(
    array(
        'foo' => 'bazbat',
        'bar' => '12345',
        'baz' => '',
        'nest' => array(
            'foo' => 'foobar',
            'bar' => '111111',
            'baz' => '',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'foo' => ' batbaz ',
        'bar' => '54321',
        'baz' => '',
    )
));
$form->isValid();
$data = $form->getData();
```

$data looks like

```
array(
    array(
        'foo' => 'bazbat',
        'bar' => '12345',
        'baz' => '',
        'nest' => array(
            'foo' => 'foobar',
            'bar' => '111111',
            'baz' => '',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'foo' => ' batbaz ',
        'bar' => '54321',
        'baz' => '',
        'nest' => array(
            'foo' => 'foobar',
            'bar' => '111111',
            'baz' => '',
        ),
    )
));
```

I'm almost positive the issue is with \Zend\InputFilter\CollectionInputFilter, but I haven't been able to find a good solution.